# Proving mathematical induction for equality

Tags: logic, induction

I need to prove the following by induction:
$$3+3^2+3^3+...+3^n=\frac{3(3^n-1)}{2}$$

I tried proving if this is true as follow:
\begin{array}{l}
\text { Prove by induction } 3+3^{2}+3^{3}+\cdots+3^{n}=\frac{3\left(3^{n}-1\right)}{2}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^{n}-1\right)\\
\mathrm{N}=1\\
\sum_{k=1}^{1} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}(3-1)\\
\mathrm{m}>0\\
\sum_{k=1}^{m} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^{m}-1\right)\\
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} 3^{k}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} 3^{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m} 3^{k}+3^{m+1}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^{\mathrm{m}}-1\right)+3^{m+1}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^{m+1}-1\right)\\
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^{m+1}-1\right)\\
\sum_{k=1}^{m} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^{\mathrm{m}}-1\right) \text { implies } \sum_{k=1}^{m+1} 3^{k}=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^{\mathrm{m}+1}-1\right)
\end{array}

Is this even remotely correct? I'm struggling to understand how induction works. Personally I feel like this is incomplete..

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Your work looks correct.  This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theory behind mathematical induction it's pretty simple:

$1)$ Check if the equality is valid for $n=1$ (or the first case in the study).

$2)$ ASSUME  it's valid for $n=n$. (or $n=n-1$) (Hypothesis).

$3)$ PROVE it's valid for $n=n+1$. (or $n=n$) (Thesis).

In your specific case:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& n=1: \quad \frac{3(3^1-1)}{2} = \frac{9-3}{2} = 3 \hspace{.2cm} \text{It's valid.} \\[5pt]
& \text{Hypothesis:}\hspace{.2cm} 3+3^2+\dots+3^n = \frac{3(3^n-1)}{2} \\[5pt]
& \text{Thesis:} \hspace{.2cm} 3+3^2+\dots+3^n+3^{n+1} = \frac{3(3^{n+1}-1)}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now, take on the left member of the thesis and try to "find" your hypothesis in there. Doing so,
\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{3 + 3^2 + \dots + 3^n}_{Hypothesis} + 3^{n+1} = \frac{3(3^n-1)}{2}+3^{n+1} = 3\left(\frac{3^n-1+2*3^n}{2}\right) = \frac{3(3^{n+1}-1)}{2}
\end{equation*}

Proving what's wanted.

My suggestion now: Try to do it using the second alternative I gave (Hypothesis for $n-1$ and Thesis for $n$).